# Copying Columns from a specific worksheet to an open worksheet based on header

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to create a macro that will pull columns from one workbook into another, based on their heading.

The source workbook changes every day so I cannot hard source the directory in.

I have a macro that works when all in one workbook but it is so heavy on resources that I am looking to split them, one for data and one for the exportable sheet.

The macro I have that will open the most recent file in the folder is:

```
'Force the explicit delcaration of variables
Option Explicit

Sub OpenLatestFile()

'Declare the variables
Dim MyPath As String
Dim MyFile As String
Dim LatestFile As String
Dim LatestDate As Date
Dim LMD As Date

'Specify the path to the folder
MyPath = "C:\Users\Domenic\Documents\"

'Make sure that the path ends in a backslash
If Right(MyPath, 1) <> "\" Then MyPath = MyPath & "\"

'Get the first Excel file from the folder
MyFile = Dir(MyPath & "*.xls", vbNormal)

'If no files were found, exit the sub
If Len(MyFile) = 0 Then
    MsgBox "No files were found...", vbExclamation
    Exit Sub
End If

'Loop through each Excel file in the folder
Do While Len(MyFile) > 0

    'Assign the date/time of the current file to a variable
    LMD = FileDateTime(MyPath & MyFile)

    'If the date/time of the current file is greater than the latest
    'recorded date, assign its filename and date/time to variables
    If LMD > LatestDate Then
        LatestFile = MyFile
        LatestDate = LMD
    End If

    'Get the next Excel file from the folder
    MyFile = Dir

Loop

'Open the latest file
Workbooks.Open MyPath & LatestFile

End Sub
```

(Taken from [here](http://www.xl-central.com/open-the-latest-file-in-a-folder.html)).

Ive then got the code that copies the correct data, but only when using one workbook:

```
Sub EditMoveColumns()
' MoveColumns Macro

' Description: Rearrange columns in Excel based on column header

Dim iRow As Long
Dim iCol As Long

'Constant values
data_sheet1 = "EDIT" 'Define MediaMath tab as the sheet to run macro on
target_sheet1 = "Filtered Edit"
iRow = Sheets(data_sheet1).UsedRange.Rows.Count 'Determine how many rows are     in use

Worksheets.Add.Name = "Filtered Edit"

'Start organizing columns
For iCol = 1 To Sheets(data_sheet1).UsedRange.Columns.Count

'Sets the TargetCol to zero in order to prevent overwriting existing   targetcolumns
TargetCol = 0

'Read the header of the original sheet to determine the column order
If Sheets(data_sheet1).Cells(7, iCol).Value = "Status" Then TargetCol = 1
If Sheets(data_sheet1).Cells(7, iCol).Value = "Trader" Then TargetCol = 2
If Sheets(data_sheet1).Cells(7, iCol).Value = "IOMT Brief ID" Then TargetCol = 3
If Sheets(data_sheet1).Cells(7, iCol).Value = " Vendor (DSP) " Then   TargetCol = 4
If Sheets(data_sheet1).Cells(7, iCol).Value = "DSP Campaign ID" Then  TargetCol = 5
If Sheets(data_sheet1).Cells(7, iCol).Value = " Client " Then TargetCol = 6
If Sheets(data_sheet1).Cells(7, iCol).Value = "Campaign" Then TargetCol = 7
If Sheets(data_sheet1).Cells(7, iCol).Value = "Buying type" Then TargetCol = 8
If Sheets(data_sheet1).Cells(7, iCol).Value = "Overall Pacing %" Then TargetCol = 9
If Sheets(data_sheet1).Cells(7, iCol).Value = "Yesterday's DSP Spend" Then TargetCol = 10
If Sheets(data_sheet1).Cells(7, iCol).Value = "Target Daily DSP Spend (Trading Currency)" Then TargetCol = 11
If Sheets(data_sheet1).Cells(7, iCol).Value = "Yesterday's DSP Impressions" Then TargetCol = 12
If Sheets(data_sheet1).Cells(7, iCol).Value = "Target Daily DSP Impressions" Then TargetCol = 13
If Sheets(data_sheet1).Cells(7, iCol).Value = "Spend Variance From Daily Target" Then TargetCol = 14
If Sheets(data_sheet1).Cells(7, iCol).Value = "Impression Variance From Daily Target" Then TargetCol = 15
If Sheets(data_sheet1).Cells(7, iCol).Value = " Country " Then TargetCol = 16
If Sheets(data_sheet1).Cells(7, iCol).Value = "CTR" Then TargetCol = 17
If Sheets(data_sheet1).Cells(7, iCol).Value = "Days Remaining" Then TargetCol = 18


'If a TargetColumn was determined (based upon the header information) then copy the column to the right spot
If TargetCol <> 0 Then
    'Select the column and copy it
    Sheets(data_sheet1).Range(Sheets(data_sheet1).Cells(7, iCol), Sheets(data_sheet1).Cells(iRow, iCol)).Copy
    Sheets(target_sheet1).Cells(1, TargetCol).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues

End If

Next iCol 'Move to the next column until all columns are read

Call Sortalphabetically

End Sub
```

So essentially I'm looking to connect these two? so that the general workload is:

- Open most recent file in directory (Or if it is simpler, this can be opened first then simply the worksheet needed can be referenced somehow - I would prefer this)
- Copy data from columns to new workbook

Answer (score 1):

Transform your `Sub OpenLatestFile()` into a function that returns the lately opened workbook:

```
Function OpenLatestFile() as Workbook
    '...
    ' At the end:
    Set OpenLatestFile = Workbooks.Open MyPath & LatestFile
End Function
```

Do the following modifications to the `Sub EditMoveColumns()`

```
Sub EditMoveColumns()
    Dim targetWB As Workbook: Set targetWB = OpenLatestFile ' <-- add this line at beginning

    ' ...

    targetWB.Worksheets.Add.Name = "Filtered Edit" '<-- modified

    ' ...
    ' Modify the body of the if statement like following
    If TargetCol <> 0 Then
        with Sheets(data_sheet1)
            targetWB.Sheets(target_sheet1).Cells(1, TargetCol).Value = _
               .Range(.Cells(7, iCol), .Cells(iRow, iCol)).Value
        End with
    End If    
' ...
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Just by transforming your `OpenLastestFile` into a function, you can call it in the other procedure :

(I've added Object references, `With`, and changed the `Copy` to improve readability and performances)

```
Sub EditMoveColumns()
' MoveColumns Macro
' Description: Rearrange columns in Excel based on column header

Dim wB As Workbook
Set wB = OpenLatestFile
Dim wSDaTa As Worksheet
Dim wSTargeT As Worksheet

Dim iRow As Long
Dim iCol As Long

'Constant values
data_sheet1 = "EDIT" 'Define MediaMath tab as the sheet to run macro on
target_sheet1 = "Filtered Edit"

Set wSDaTa = wB.Sheets(data_sheet1)
Set wSTargeT = wB.Worksheets.Add
wSTargeT.Name = target_sheet1

With wSDaTa
    iRow = .UsedRange.Rows.Count 'Determine how many rows are     in use
    'Start organizing columns
    For iCol = 1 To .UsedRange.Columns.Count
        'Sets the TargetCol to zero in order to prevent overwriting existing   targetcolumns
        TargetCol = 0
        'Read the header of the original sheet to determine the column order
        With .Cells(7, iCol)
            If .Value = "Status" Then TargetCol = 1
            If .Value = "Trader" Then TargetCol = 2
            If .Value = "IOMT Brief ID" Then TargetCol = 3
            If .Value = " Vendor (DSP) " Then TargetCol = 4
            If .Value = "DSP Campaign ID" Then TargetCol = 5
            If .Value = " Client " Then TargetCol = 6
            If .Value = "Campaign" Then TargetCol = 7
            If .Value = "Buying type" Then TargetCol = 8
            If .Value = "Overall Pacing %" Then TargetCol = 9
            If .Value = "Yesterday's DSP Spend" Then TargetCol = 10
            If .Value = "Target Daily DSP Spend (Trading Currency)" Then TargetCol = 11
            If .Value = "Yesterday's DSP Impressions" Then TargetCol = 12
            If .Value = "Target Daily DSP Impressions" Then TargetCol = 13
            If .Value = "Spend Variance From Daily Target" Then TargetCol = 14
            If .Value = "Impression Variance From Daily Target" Then TargetCol = 15
            If .Value = " Country " Then TargetCol = 16
            If .Value = "CTR" Then TargetCol = 17
            If .Value = "Days Remaining" Then TargetCol = 18
        End With '.Cells(7, iCol)
        'If a TargetColumn was determined (based upon the header information) then copy the column to the right spot
        If TargetCol <> 0 Then
            'Transfer Data directly to the target sheet!
             wSTargeT.Range(wSTargeT.Cells(1, TargetCol), wSTargeT.Cells(iRow - 6, TargetCol)).Value = _
                 .Range(.Cells(7, iCol), .Cells(iRow, iCol)).Value

        End If
    Next iCol 'Move to the next column until all columns are read
End With 'wSDaTa

Call Sortalphabetically
End Sub
```

And the function

```
Private Function OpenLatestFile() As Workbook
'Declare the variables
Dim MyPath As String
Dim MyFile As String
Dim LatestFile As String
Dim LatestDate As Date
Dim LMD As Date

'Specify the path to the folder
MyPath = "C:\Users\Domenic\Documents\"
'Make sure that the path ends in a backslash
If Right(MyPath, 1) <> "\" Then MyPath = MyPath & "\"
'Get the first Excel file from the folder
MyFile = Dir(MyPath & "*.xls", vbNormal)
'If no files were found, exit the sub
If Len(MyFile) = 0 Then
    MsgBox "No files were found...", vbExclamation
    Exit Function
End If

'Loop through each Excel file in the folder
Do While Len(MyFile) > 0
    'Assign the date/time of the current file to a variable
    LMD = FileDateTime(MyPath & MyFile)
    'If the date/time of the current file is greater than the latest
    'recorded date, assign its filename and date/time to variables
    If LMD > LatestDate Then
        LatestFile = MyFile
        LatestDate = LMD
    End If
    'Get the next Excel file from the folder
    MyFile = Dir
Loop
'Open the latest file
Set OpenLatestFile = Workbooks.Open(MyPath & LatestFile)

End Function
```

Comment: Thank you so much! The bulk of it works, the worksheet opens and the target sheet is created. but then i get

    Object doesn't support this property or method

    wSTargeT.Range(wSTargeT.Cells(1, TargetCol), wSTargeT.Cells(iRow - 6, TargetCol)).Value = _
                 .Range(.Cells(7, iCol), .Cells(iRow, iCol)).Values

On those 2 lines (Basically the end of the code)

Also, is there a way I can run that without opening the file?

Cheers

Comment: @JoeElding : You get... what?

Comment: Sorry, i was expecting formating in a comment to stay the same, I get runtime error:

"Object doesn't support this property or method"

Comment: @JoeElding : My bad, I missed an `s` in `.Values` so it didn't work! Try the new edit without it!